# Download files from firebase Storage with php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-storage

i am new in firebase web if it possible to upload, download, and delete file using php. i have upload file using JS but i want to download using PHP.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) is script of download file using JS but i want in PHP.

Thanks in advance...

My Code

```
[START storage_quickstart]
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'My project ID';

# Instantiates a client
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

# The name for the new bucket
$bucketName = 'my bucket';

# Creates the new bucket
$bucket = $storage->createBucket($bucketName);

echo 'Bucket ' . $bucket->name() . ' created.';
# [END storage_quickstart]
return $bucket;
```

Comment: Firebase provides SDKs for client-side access to your stored files. PHP is a server-side language. To access your stored files from the server, you can use the Google Cloud Storage APIs and SDK. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php

Comment: go to their documentation

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for informed me. But i have geting error this https://www.screencast.com/t/qcX1JTdeuR type ..i have edit my question with using my code.. please help me

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should use [`gcloud-php`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/). This requires that you set up a service account (or use Google Compute Engine/Container Engine/App Engine which provide default credentials).

It's likely that you'll [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#generating-a-private-key), download a `keyfile.json`, and provide it as an argument to the StorageClient, like so:

```
# Instantiates a client
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/key/file.json',
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);
```

Alternatively, it looks like they've built another layer of abstraction, which takes the same arguments but allows you to use lots of other services:

```
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;

$gcloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/key/file.json',
    'projectId' => 'myProject'
]);

$storage = $gcloud->storage();

$bucket = $storage->bucket('myBucket');
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer me. in this answer getting bulk array result. if you have more info please share here.. i don't have used of "firebase database".. i have only used "firebase storage".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, sorry. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I want to download media files from firebase. So I could get the media url and show images to my site. but I failed to get download url from firebase php api. and got many error while running the script. Is there any proper way to do with success or any working example you can show me ?

here is the screenshot from fire base storage  https://www.screencast.com/t/xbhPuIqH

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question, but I was struggling with same problem... hope my solution help someone.
In fact, I really don't know if there is an official way to do that, but I created the method below and it worked for me.

```
function storageFileUrl($name, $path = []) {
    $base = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/';
    $projectId = 'your-project-id';

    $url = $base.$projectId.'/o/';
    if(sizeof($path) > 0) {
        $url .= implode('%2F', $path).'%2F';
    }
    return $url.$name.'?alt=media';
}
```

To access files in the root of bucket:

```
$address = storageFileUrl('myFile');
```

Result: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your-project-id.appspot.com/o/myFile?alt=media

To access files inside some folder, do:

```
$address = storageFileUrl('myFile', ['folder', 'subfolder']);
```

Result: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your-project-id.appspot.com/o/folder%2Fsubfolder%2FmyFile?alt=media

Enjoy.